# Getting Error while writing the test cases

Tags: spring-boot, junit, mockito, powermockito

java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/mockito/cglib/proxy/MethodInterceptor

ServiceBusReceivedMessageContext is final class

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hFnps.png)

Can anyone help on this?
I am not sure why this is showing like this. Does this a dependency issue?
This final class has final variables as well.

```
`@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
@PrepareForTest(ServiceBusReceivedMessageContext.class)
public class DirectMessageProcessorTest {

    @InjectMocks
    DirectMessageProcessor directMessageProcessor;

    @Test
    void processMessageTest() throws Exception{
            System.out.println("Stated running test cases");
            ServiceBusReceivedMessageContext serviceBusReceivedMessageContext = PowerMockito.mock(ServiceBusReceivedMessageContext.class);
    }
}
`
```